# How to get a consistent sha1 across all app instances with flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sha1

Im writing a flutter mobile app that requires the use of firebases authentication product which in turn requires the use of sha1. I am on a small team and to get each instance of the app to work on each persons computer we needed to register a new sha1 address per computer, this is fine for debugging purposes but obviously cant be done in production. How do you get a consistent sha1 across all the app instances so that each new user does not have to register a unique sha1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate release APK, you will be creating a **key** in Keystore (*a private file*), from which you would extract out your *release **SHA1** key*. This would be the consistent SHA1 key for all the users downloading the app.

You just need to add this *release SHA1 key* in your Firebase console.

Kindly refer here for more details about building an android application in flutter: [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

On production, you will get a signing key from Google Play and you will add that to firebase and it will generate a new google-services.json file for you. you will be fine on production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are releasing the app to the stores then you have to generate a key store as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-a-keystore) then you need to add this SHA-1 finger print in the firebase console.

To view the SHA1-1 finger print of the above generated key store then execute below command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

You can see the SHA-1 finger print in the terminal and add the same in firebase console